# Sorting XML data based on number of characters in data

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to sort my XML output based on the the number of characters in the data. I haven't been able to figure it out so far in XSLT 1.0. Here is what I am working with:

Source XML File:

```
<ROOT>
<REPLIST>
    <NAME>ABCDE.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>ABCDEFGH.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>ABC.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>ABCDEFG.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>ABCD.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>ABCDEF.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>JKLMNOPQRST.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>JKLMNOPQRS.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>JKLMNOPQ.xml</NAME>
    <NAME>JKLMN.xml</NAME>
</REPLIST>
<DATALIST>
    <ExtractedName>ABCDEFGH.xml</ExtractedName>
    <ExtractedName>JKLMN.xml</ExtractedName>
    <ExtractedName>ABCDEFG.xml</ExtractedName>
    <ExtractedName>ABCD.xml</ExtractedName>
    <ExtractedName>JKLMNOPQRST.xml</ExtractedName>
    <ExtractedName>ABCDEFG.xml</ExtractedName>
</DATALIST>
</ROOT>
```

Output

```
<TestData>
<FormName>ABCDEFGH</FormName>
<FormName>ABCDEFG</FormName>
<FormName>ABCD</FormName>
<FormName>JKLMNOPQRST</FormName>
<FormName>JKLMN</FormName>
</TestData>
```

Desired Output:

```
<TestData>
<FormName>JKLMNOPQRST</FormName>
<FormName>ABCDEFGH</FormName>
<FormName>ABCDEFG</FormName>
<FormName>JKLMN</FormName>
<FormName>ABCD</FormName>
</TestData>
```

Stylesheet ( 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <TestData>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </TestData>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ROOT/REPLIST/NAME[.=/ROOT/DATALIST/ExtractedName]">
    <FormName>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'.xml','')"/>
    </FormName>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
</xsl:template>
```

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A shorter, simpler, and more robust solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kNameByVal" match="NAME" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="REPLIST">
  <TestData>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "key('kNameByVal', /*/DATALIST/*)">
     <xsl:sort select="-string-length()" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </TestData>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="NAME">
  <FormName><xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1, string-length()-4)"/></FormName>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ROOT>
    <REPLIST>
        <NAME>ABCDE.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>ABCDEFGH.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>ABC.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>ABCDEFG.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>ABCD.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>ABCDEF.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>JKLMNOPQRST.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>JKLMNOPQRS.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>JKLMNOPQ.xml</NAME>
        <NAME>JKLMN.xml</NAME>
    </REPLIST>
    <DATALIST>
        <ExtractedName>ABCDEFGH.xml</ExtractedName>
        <ExtractedName>JKLMN.xml</ExtractedName>
        <ExtractedName>ABCDEFG.xml</ExtractedName>
        <ExtractedName>ABCD.xml</ExtractedName>
        <ExtractedName>JKLMNOPQRST.xml</ExtractedName>
        <ExtractedName>ABCDEFG.xml</ExtractedName>
    </DATALIST>
</ROOT>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<TestData>
   <FormName>JKLMNOPQRST</FormName>
   <FormName>ABCDEFGH</FormName>
   <FormName>ABCDEFG</FormName>
   <FormName>JKLMN</FormName>
   <FormName>ABCD</FormName>
</TestData>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no"/>
  <xsl:key name="kExtract" match="ExtractedName" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <TestData>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="REPLIST/NAME[key('kExtract', .)]">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before(., '.xml'))"
                  data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </TestData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="REPLIST/NAME">
    <FormName>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.xml')"/>
    </FormName>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<TestData>
  <FormName>JKLMNOPQRST</FormName>
  <FormName>ABCDEFGH</FormName>
  <FormName>ABCDEFG</FormName>
  <FormName>JKLMN</FormName>
  <FormName>ABCD</FormName>
</TestData>
```